# How to find the fixed point of a complex function ? It seems impossible to solve it directly.

Tags: complex-analysis

In a math text I wasn't able to solve this problem :
Consider the complex function $f(z)=2iz+8i$
Determine the fixed point of f.

I tried solving the $f(z_1)=z_1$ for $z_1=a+ib$
but I can't cancel out the variable and the equation is under defined.

Therefore :
$f(z_1)=z_1$

$-2b+2i(4+a)=a+ib$

$8i+2ia-a=ib+2b$ then separating the complex from the real part : $(a+2b)-i(8+2a-b)=0$

Comment: You should show your work so we can help.  It looks like $z=\frac{8i}{1-2i}$ is a fixed point, just from doing the algebra.  Can you get that far?

Comment: The inelegant approach is to set $~z = (x + iy),~$ and solve for $~x,y~$ via $$x + iy = 2i(x + iy) + 8i.$$

Comment: Um.... so we have $2i(a+ib) +8i = a + bi$.  Just expand it out.

Comment: It's so  much easier to do this in one variable ($z$) instead of two ($a,b$).  Either way, it works out.

Comment: So you just got $a = -2b$ and $2a + 8 = b$.  Two equations two unknowns.

Comment: When you reach the point that $~R + iS = 0, ~R,S \in \Bbb{R},~$ this implies that $~R = 0~$ and $~S = 0.$

Comment: Substitue $a=-2b$ into $2a + 8 = b$ to get $2(-2b) + 8 = b$ to solve for $b$ and plug that value of $b$ back into $a$.

Comment: Okay..... I guess the point you are not realizing is that  $z_1 = z_2 \iff Re(z_1)=Re(z_2)\text{ and }Im(z_1) = Im(z_2)$.  So $a+bi = c+di \iff (a=c, b=d)$.  And so $-2b + (2a+8)i = a + bi \iff -2b =a\text { and } 2a+8 = b$.

Comment: On the other hand.... you have $z = 2iz + 8i$ so $z - 2iz = 8i$ and $z(1-2i) = 8i$ and $z = \frac {8i}{1-2i}$ and that the complex number.  You can do algebra on complex numbers *just like you can on real number*.   Were you *asked* to put it in $Re(z) + R(z)i$ form?  If so $\frac {8i}{1-2i} = \frac {8i(1+2i)}{(1-2i)(1+2i)} = \frac {8i -16}{1+4} = \frac {-16}5 + \frac 85i$.  That's it.

Comment: Thank you I see it now ! What would be an elegant way to solve this problem ?

Comment: If that's what you want to do, conjugate it.

Comment: You are a boss @fleablood !!